# How to delete a column if contains 2 different texts at the same label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some columns that I want to delete. I already know how to delete a column if I find some specified text, as:

```
df.drop(columns=[col for col in df.columns if 'text.'in str(col)],inplace=True)
```

I would like to also delete the columns which contains, along the total text, different patterns, as:

"***text.Corolary.sub.ramdon.sta***", "***text.paint.ss1b.docto.not.sta***"

I want to delet all the columns which contains **"text."** but also **".sta"**. How can I combine it in the same command independently of the rest of the text?

Comment: i think there are better ways to drop columns with specified text than what you have. It would be helpful tho, if you provided a sample dataframe with ur expected output. Kindly use this as a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and masks chain by `&` for bitwise `AND`, last filter by inverse masks by `~`:

```
m1 = df.columns.str.contains('text')
m2 = df.columns.str.contains('\.sta')
#alternative
#m2 = df.columns.str.contains('.sta', regex=False)

mask = m1 & m2
df = df.loc[:, ~mask]
```